# Java Localized test fails on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

We are testing some features of our software, and some of them are working with a Locale.
So, when we test in our machines, all tests runs, but in Jenkins some test using locale (java locale) fails.

Here's an example:

```
@Test
public void testCurrencyFormat_withCLPFormat_returnValidFormat() {

    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("500456.789");
    java.util.Currency currency = java.util.Currency
            .getInstance(chileLocale);
    Currency c = new Currency(currency);

    assertEquals("500.456,789",
            defaultCurrencyFormatter.format(c, amount, chileLocale));

}
```

Note that the locale it's setted for use the right locale for the test.
Like i said, in my machine the test run without problems, but in jenkins it fails:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<500[.456,]789> but was:<500[,456.]789>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:125)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
at cl.taisachile.antaios.domain.currency.CurrencyTest.testCurrencyFormat_withCLPFormat_returnValidFormat(CurrencyTest.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

EDIT:

I manually run the test on the server. I installed jenkins using yum on CentOS, so, Jenkins has his own user. If i run the test using the default login user to the server, all run's ok. But, when i log in into the jenkins user, the test's fails. I think it's not jenkis or the code. But i don't see where is the difference.
Any Help?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 2:
Just for the record: We changed the setup of the server and the errors disapear.
We tested several configurations and couldn't determine why fails on centos/32bits.
Thanks for all.

Comment: It looks like the locale is not taken into account. How is the Locale configured in Jenkins?

Comment: I think isn't a problem for the jenkins locale, because the test set the desired locale to run. In this case is "es-CL".

Comment: How is `defaultCurrencyFormatter` created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it is a problem of the Java version installed on the test (Jenkins) machine, maybe it is a problem of your code.

You do not show how the `chileLocale` is instantiated, there could be a problem.
Also you do not show the code of your `defaultCurrencyFormatter` and `Currency` object, which are under test.

This test should show you the systems definitions for the decimal and group separators for the es-CL locale:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale chileLocale = new Locale("es", "CL");
    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(chileLocale);

    char sep = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
    char grp = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator();

    System.out.println("Separator: " + sep + " Grouping: " + grp);
}
```

If they differ on your different systems, then you should have a look at the Java installation, which is then obviously the problem.

**EDIT:**
Another note:
Keep in mind that standard Java `NumberFormat` and its derivatives are not thread-save.
If you are accessing the same formatter instance from different threads, you might run into trouble.
Make sure to have single formatter instance per thread.

Comment: `defaultCurrencyFormatter` and `chileLocale` are both not part of your test method, therefore they are candidates of a possible multi threading issue. Also they may have an error in instantiation/implementation. Move the instantiation of both into the test method itself, do not use a class variable for them. Also show us the code for them, if that doesn't help.

Comment: chilocale it's `Locale chileLocale = new Locale("es", "CL");`. The other class just do some code for Chilean format to currencies that are not supported. But, again, maybe the problem it's the server and not the test. Those tests run in every developer machine, but not in the server. I to manually run the job (-U clean install) and the test doesn't fail.